# Asp.Net user keyboard tabbing with onfocus/__doPostBack

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have an onfocus event with __doPostBack for a couple dozen or so textbox's on a page. If the user  tabs (tabkey) really fast to get to a specific textbox it lags because its trying to fullfill each onfocus. Is there way to catch the delay between focusing of controls?

Comment: You want it to do a full post back for every focus change?  Is that what you're saying?  Wouldn't the page be almost unusable?

Comment: Ya, I hear ya, i was tasked to replicate a windows application. I think instead of doing a __doPostBack, a webservice would be better.

Comment: Do you have to perfectly replicate the UI?  Any chance that you can introduce a final postback after all the entry is done?  That would be a heck of a lot less work for you!

Comment: Not on this one. Each group of controls and code for those controls is created dynamically from database. The code from the db is compiled separtely and I invoke it when they are in the corresponding control. My Web App is simply a container. So I am at the mercy of someonelse structure and logic.